# Removing text within parentheses and trailing spaces

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

I am using Rubular for this. I have the following string:

```
summary = "Hi world. Hi world. Hi world. Hi world. Hi world. Hi world. Hi world. Hi world (this is here). Hi world Hi world (wow)."
```

I'm trying to remove all parentheses from the string with the following:

```
summary.gsub!(/\([^()]*\)/,"")
```

The problem is this is not grabbing the space, so it results as follows:

"Hi world. Hi world. Hi world. Hi world. Hi world. Hi world. Hi world. Hi world . Hi world Hi world ."

Notice the undesired space before the period. How can I update the regex to remove the extra space that is being left over when I remove the parentheses?

Comment: Use `summary.gsub!(/\s*\([^()]*\)/,"")`

Comment: BTW, what about `(Remove) This text is ok (remove). `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really just a minor modification to make it capture the spaces, too, if there are any:

```
summary.gsub!(/\s*\([^\)]*\)/, '')
```

That will only capture leading spaces. If you want leading and trailing:

```
summary.gsub!(/\s*\([^\)]*\)\s*/, '')
```